# Tutorials for Natural Language Classifier - 500 error occurred

Tags: ibm-cloud

I wanted to create a classifier, so following the tutorial I did the following :

```
curl -i -u "apikey:{apikey}" \
-F training_data=@{train.csv} \
-F training_metadata="{\"language\":\"en\",\"name\":\"TutorialClassifier\"}" \
"{url}/v1/classifiers"
```

But, the following 500 error occurs:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT: 0
X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency: 113

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 176
Expires: Wed, 11 Mar 2020 04:44:04 GMT
Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2020 04:44:04 GMT
Connection: close

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
An error occurred while processing your request.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;179&#46;35e52e17&#46;1583901844&#46;39c6106
</BODY></HTML>
```

What is causing this error?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the link to the tutorial you are following?

Comment: The following page.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/natural-language-classifier?topic=natural-language-classifier-natural-language-classifier&locale=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions in the tutorial and able to create a classifier without any error. Here are the request and response

**Request:**

```
curl -i -u "apikey:API_KEY" \
-F training_data=@weather_data_train.csv \
-F training_metadata="{\"language\":\"en\",\"name\":\"TutorialClassifier\"}" \
"URL/v1/classifiers"
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT: 230
X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency: 95

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 449
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
x-global-transaction-id: xxxxxxx
X-DP-Watson-Tran-ID: xxxxxx
X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT: 230
X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency: 2000
X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT: 230
X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency: 95
Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2020 07:05:02 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "classifier_id" : "xxxxx",
  "name" : "TutorialClassifier",
  "language" : "en",
  "created" : "2020-03-11T07:05:01.126Z",
  "url" : "URL/v1/classifiers/xxx",
  "status_description" : "The classifier instance is in its training phase, not yet ready to accept classify requests",
  "status" : "Training"
}%
```

All I did is

- Create the Natural Language Classifier service.
- Download the `.csv` and `.json` files.
- On a terminal or command prompt, point to the folder where I downloaded the `.csv` and `.json` files.
- From the service credentials page of the service, copy the `apikey` and `url` values and replace the placeholders ({apikey}, {url}) in the `curl` command.
- Execute the command to see the above response.

Comment: I did everything you did and was able to create a classifier without errors. The 500 error was probably caused by a wrong API key. Thanks for your answer.